# ASP MVC Route issue with dot "."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have this route:

> file{FileId}/{name}

It works perfectly unless `name` has a dot in it.

For example, these work:

> file1/blah, file90/foo -

but it doesn't:

> file1/blah.doc

All I get in this case is `404 error`. Seems like it looks for the actual file `blah.doc` instead of use routing system.

This problem happens only in production server. I've even tried

> httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Everything after the '.' is the file extension. If that extension isn't mapped to ASP.NET, it won't get handed off to the ASP.NET handler. IIS looks for a static file instead. So you need to add a handler for your case (web.config), then your route will be able to catch the request.

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   <handlers>
      <add name="FileHandlerDot" verb="GET" path="file*/*.*" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
   </handlers>
</validation>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will have some ugly side-effects.

Comment: In my case I can restrict the path to a couple of endpoints that need to handle /Users/Detail/forename.surname and this solution works fine. A site wide handler would be a mistake but for me this is a viable solution. + 1